# Недопустимый тип операнда

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ассемблер

Мне нужно взять в переменную в ассемблерной вставке значение по адресу, содержащемуся в регистре [EBP]:

```
size_t esp_val = 0;
size_t esp_var = 0;
size_t ecx_var = 0;
__asm {
    mov esp_var, ESP
    mov ecx_var, ECX
    mov esp_val, [EBP]
}
```

Но в последней строке `mov esp_val, [EBP]` я неизменно получаю ошибку

> Недопустимый тип операнда

Пробовал менять тип на DWORD. В сети встречал вариант в таком духе:

```
mov esp_val, SIZE_T PTR[EBP]

mov esp_val, DWORD PTR[EBP]
```

При чем такое впечатление, что у всех это работает кроме меня.

Я что-то упускаю?

Comment: `mov esp_val, DWORD PTR[EBP]` - вряд ли вы где-то такое встречали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я помню ассемблер, вы пытаетесь сделать пересылку память-память непосредственно, а такой команды нет.

Перебрасывайте в регистр, а регистр - в переменную - типа:

```
__asm {
    mov esp_var, ESP
    mov ecx_var, ECX
    mov eax, [EBP]
    mov esp_val, eax
}
```